# Restore session with Hybrid Auth

Tags: php, authentication, session-cookies, hybridauth

I recently implemented Hybrid Auth into my website, and I have to say that it's very well written and easy to get working. There were some minor problems I overcame but the base is in there and functional as far as my test goes...

However, under the example of Persistent sessions in their user guide (http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/HybridAuth_Sessions.html), there's something I don't get, or understand how they mean to proceed:

> For the sake of this example, let assume we have a user which the id on your application is $current_user_id, and we are going to use a database table to store hybridauth session data.

So storing the information with an ID for the user isn't a problem, neither is fetching it really, but how do they mean to obtain $current_user_id when the user revisits the site after some time? The only way I can think of is setting a $_COOKIE with their ID, because every session cookie gets destroyed on logout. But is that really what they're implying? If so, I would have to prompt the user (supposedly after they log in) whether they want to remain logged in or not. Am I right on this or would there be another way the system intends?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but yes, your should store the user's internal ID in a cookie, then use the methodds getSessionData and storeSessionData to store/get session data from your database based on the user's internal ID. Your app should be in sync with the user's social logins. That is, if he logs off your site, he also logs off all the social logins at the same time. If he is no longer logged into a social login, he should no longer be logged into your site unless he reauthenticates. That's what HybridAuth is set up to do for you.